# How to wrap normal image tag with figure HTML5 element

Tags: images

This is what i am trying to achieve: --
[image]

Code i am trying in wordpress:-

```
function html5_insert_image($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url) {

    $html5 = get_image_tag( $id, $alt,$url, '', $align, $size );
    $html5 = "<figure id='post-$id media-$id' class='align-$align'>";
    $html5 .= "<img src='$url' alt='$title' />";
    if ($caption) {
      $html5 .= "<figcaption>$caption</figcaption>";
    }
    $html5 .= "</figure>";
    return $html5;
   }
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'html5_insert_image', 10, 9 );
```

issue is here url is not getting printed image source ,i tried many code from post from stack or other source but not working.

Or will be best if anyone can help with the code what i wanted. I mean with first example.

Theme support for HTML5 is added theme.

Comment: WordPress already uses a figure tag. This shouldn’t be necessary. Have you registered support for HTML5? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_theme_support/#html5 Although I’m pretty sure you don’t even need to do that if you’re using the block editor.

Comment: Oh , some of my code is removed , i mean like what i like to achive but with above code i am unable to get the url of images so i can use image url in other elements. `<figure class="post__figure">
<picture class="picture lazy">
<source media="(max-width: 360px)" data-srcset="./img/post/post-6/360/image-5.webp">
<source media="(min-width: 360px)" data-srcset="./img/post/post-6/image-5.webp">
<img class="image" alt="image 5">
</picture>
<figcaption class="caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut.</figcaption>
</figure>`

Comment: the code in your question uses `get_image_tag` then immediately resets the value of `$html5` to something else and never attempts to include any image tags. Can I ask, why do you want to do this? As Jacob said WP already uses figure elements so you doo not need to write code to addd them yourself. Why do you need to do this? What is the problem you are solving?

Comment: I can see any figure tag by default in WordPress classic page builder. for some reason i am not able to comment the full desired code in question section. I have added the same code in the comment to jacob. what is needed. I have got it sorted out 90% i guess.  issue left now,  when i am using captions in images then  all html code wrapping inside captions shortcode.  Actually i got this requirement from my client.

Comment: Finally it just worked out. I had to disable captions using WordPress filter . for some reason not able to share full code here .